# CSS3: Bone shape

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

> How to make a grid with dog bone format in CSS and/or jQuery? The
>   format of bone is this:

[image]

> And the grid would look like this, just that out instead of hexagonal and the content (image/text) inside
>   format would bone:
>   [image]
>
> It is possible to create this format?

Comment: You might be able to do this if you're clever with radial gradients…

Comment: Not sure if trolling or not ... hmm :D

Comment: for a hexagon grid, you may see the pen : http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you draw bone.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JvdKk/)

HTML

```
<div class="bone">
    <div class="s1"></div>
    <div class="s2"></div>
    <div class="s3"></div>
    <div class="s4"></div>
    <div class="centerbone">
      <div class="clean"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bone{
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
.s1, .s2, .s3, .s4{
  background:#fff;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 200px;
  position:absolute;
}
.s1{
  left: 0;
}
.s2{
  right: 0;
}
.s3{
  top: 205px;
}
.s4{
  right: 0;
  top:205px;
}
.centerbone{
  background:#fff;
  height: 250px;
  width: 188px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  position:absolute;  
  left: 205px;
  top: 78px;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px;
}
.clean{
  background:#fff;
  width: 400px;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:-104px;
}
```

And for hexagon grid, follow this tutorial:

http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html