# Custom Shaped CSS3 Price Table

Tags: html, css, customization, shapes

I'm trying to create a price table shaped like a bone. I found some code on code pen but I'm not sure how to modify/combine it.

I'm having trouble posting the links to the code but the bone shape is here:

[CSS3: Bone shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004554/css3-bone-shape)

http://codepen.io/Rv-Designs/pen/fthsp

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  font-family: trebuchet MS;
  color: #6B6B6B;
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  padding: 60px 0px;
}
.container {} .row {} .circle {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 8px solid #F2F2F2;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Opera */
}
.circle h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.circle p {} .circle span {} .circle span.icon {} .circle span.icon i {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.circle span.price-large {
  font-size: 68px
}
.price-small {
  font-size: 24px
}
.c1:hover {
  background: #39b3d7;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c1 .blue {
  color: #39b3d7;
}
.c1:hover .blue {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c2:hover {
  background: #ed9c28;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c2 .yellow {
  color: #ed9c28;
}
.c2:hover .yellow {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c3:hover {
  background: #47a447;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c3 .green {
  color: #47a447;
}
.c3:hover .green {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c4:hover {
  background: #d2322d;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c4 .red {
  color: #d2322d;
}
.c4:hover .red {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="circle c1 img-circle">
          <h4 class="blue">Basic Plan</h4>
          <span class="icon blue"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
          <span class="price-large blue">8,</span>
          <span class="price-small">90</span>
          <p>Great for small Business</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Choose</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="circle c2 img-circle">
          <h4 class="yellow">Starter Plan</h4>
          <span class="icon yellow"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
          <span class="price-large yellow">24,</span>
          <span class="price-small">90</span>
          <p>Great for small Business</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Choose</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="circle c3 img-circle">
          <h4 class="green">Premier Plan</h4>
          <span class="icon green"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
          <span class="price-large green">54,</span>
          <span class="price-small">90</span>
          <p>Great for small Business</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Choose</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="circle c4 img-circle">
          <h4 class="red">Deluxe Plan</h4>
          <span class="icon red"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
          <span class="price-large red">8,</span>
          <span class="price-small">90</span>
          <p>Great for small Business</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Choose</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->
    </div>
    <!-- .Container ends here -->
  </div>
  <!-- .Row ends here -->
</div>
```

Something like this: 
http://s9.postimg.org/u6np6fk73/example_01.jpg

Comment: The code pen has rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 
* {
 padding:0; 
 margin:0; 
 border:0;
}

body {
   background: #d5d5d5;
 font-family:trebuchet MS;
 color:#6B6B6B;
   border: 0 none;
   margin: 0;
 font-size:13px;
   padding: 0;
}
#wrapper{
  padding: 60px 0px;
}
.container{}
.row{}
.circle{
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;

    
    transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: all 0.5s; /* Opera */
 
}
.circle h4{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.circle p{}
.circle span{}
.circle span.icon{
}
.circle span.icon i{
  font-size: 48px;
}
.circle span.price-large{
  font-size: 68px
}
.price-small{
  font-size: 24px 
}

.c1:hover{
  background: #39b3d7;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c1 .blue{
  color: #39b3d7;
}
.c1:hover .blue{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.c2:hover{
  background: #ed9c28;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c2 .yellow{
  color: #ed9c28;
}
.c2:hover .yellow{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.c3:hover{
  background: #47a447;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c3 .green{
  color: #47a447;
}
.c3:hover .green{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.c4:hover{
  background: #d2322d;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.c4 .red{
  color: #d2322d;
}
.c4:hover .red{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bone-container {position: relative; margin: 0 auto; height: 520px; width: auto}
.bone-container:before,
.bone-container:after
{content: ''; position: absolute; left: 130px; right: 140px; display: block; background: #fff}
.bone-container:before {top: 120px; bottom: 120px; border: 8px solid #f2f2f2}
.bone-container:after {top: 128px; bottom: 128px}


.bone-container .circle {position: relative; z-index: 10}

.shape-1,
.shape-2,
.shape-3,
.shape-4 {position: absolute; width: 265px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; border: 8px solid #F2F2F2; border-radius: 50%; padding: 0px}

.shape-1 {top: 0px; left: 0}
.shape-2 {top: 0px; right: 15px}
.shape-3 {bottom: 0; right: 15px}
.shape-4 {bottom: 0; left: 0}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row bone-container">
              <div class="shape-1 col-md-3">
                  <div class="circle c1 img-circle">
                      <h4 class="blue">Basic Plan</h4>
                      <span class="icon blue"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
                      <span class="price-large blue">8,</span>
                      <span class="price-small">90</span>
                      <p>Great for small Business</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Choose</button>
                  </div>
              </div><!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->
          
              <div class="shape-2 col-md-3">
                  <div class="circle c2 img-circle">
                      <h4 class="yellow">Starter Plan</h4>
                      <span class="icon yellow"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
                      <span class="price-large yellow">24,</span>
                      <span class="price-small">90</span>
                      <p>Great for small Business</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Choose</button>
                  </div>
              </div><!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->
          
          <div class="shape-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="circle c3 img-circle">
                      <h4 class="green">Premier Plan</h4>
                      <span class="icon green"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
                      <span class="price-large green">54,</span>
                      <span class="price-small">90</span>
                      <p>Great for small Business</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Choose</button>
                  </div>
              </div><!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->
          
          <div class="shape-4 col-md-3">
                  <div class="circle c4 img-circle">
                      <h4 class="red">Deluxe Plan</h4>
                      <span class="icon red"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>
                      <span class="price-large red">8,</span>
                      <span class="price-small">90</span>
                      <p>Great for small Business</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Choose</button>
                  </div>
              </div><!-- .Col-md-3 ends here -->
        </div><!-- .Container ends here -->
    </div><!-- .Row ends here -->
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmOdz

Comment: Thanks @adamlencz this helps a lot, but is there a way to get the text/price in the centre of the bone (the rectangle) ?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one shape rather than with 5 separate ones @adamlencz?

Comment: Can you add an image so that I could see what would you exactly like to achieve?

Comment: see image link above just added.